# Error when running tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run the first example ("MNIST For ML Beginners") from tensorflow tutorial with Python 2.7.10 and getting the following error:

```
_pywrap_tensorflow.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromStringAndSize
```

If I rebuild Python with

> --enable-unicode=ucs4

I am getting another problem:

```
multiarray.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_AsASCIIString
```

Does anyone know how I can workaround this?

Comment: Sure, I saw it and installed [as I thought] numpy with the ucs4-built python. However, pip appeared to be from another Python installation, so there was an example of versions hell.

Comment: @SalvadorDali I would not be so sure. I am having the same problem as OP, and the link you provided does not help.

Comment: "A person has done 0 attempt to at least search for a problem" - this is not correct, you may see the relation between what is suggested by you and what I initially stated in my question (ucs4). Of course I saw this question.

Comment: @YuliaSh. But the question mentions that you should rebuild numpy with your new python. Did you do that?

Comment: @YuliaSh. it is hard to guess the relationship just based on 4 characters. Please if you have done some attempts while solving your problem, write them clearly. Explain something like: I have done 1) (link), explanation. This resulted in the following error. I also have done 2) which results in many warnings (w1, w2, w3) but import still fails with e1. This way everyone who reads the question knows what already does not work, and no one is guessing.